# Comparing the Stacks Project Homotopy limit with limits in the $\infty$-category

Tags: homological-algebra, infinity-categories

In the Stacks project Tag 08TC, there is a definition of a homotopy limit in a derived category, and I expect it to compare with a limit in the $\infty$-categorical enhancement. I guess this is also hinted at in the beginning of the proof of
Proposition 1.2.1.19 in Lurie's Higher Algebra. However, I have trouble to write down the details. Could someone clarify this for me please? Also, is there a reference available?

Alternatively, is there a way to see this through the Bousfield-Kan formula?

Comment: There is a reference in an appendix of HTT - I'll try to locate it when I find the time. But it is rather explicit in HTT

Answer (score 5):

There is a reference for this in Lurie's *Higher topos theory* - specifically, see Theorem 4.2.4.1, Corollary 4.2.4.8.

The key to these is Proposition 4.2.4.4, which itself relies heavily on Appendix A in *HTT*. In some sense, Appendix A is *the* place for all these comparisons between model-theoretic concepts and their $\infty$-categorical analogue.

Comment: This is just a sequential system and I guess that it is much easier than anything using model categories. Namely, you only have to identify countable products and equalizers (or fibers).

Comment: The question was about "homotopy limits", I guess I didn't check the Stacks project to see what special case it was. Also I thought I might as well cite the appropriate generality. @Z.M